# Add a JScrollPane to a JLabel

Tags: java, html, swing, jscrollpane

I can't seem to find out how I can add a `JScrollPane` to a `JLabel`. The `JLabel` that I'm using is populated with a long formatted HTML string. Please help.

```
area = new JLabel();

JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(area, 
      JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, 
      JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

panel.add(scroller);
```

Comment: Why use a JLabel then? and not JTextArea and set it to be not editable?

Comment: Without posting code it's impossible for those of us without ESP to tell what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 7):

Really not good idea to hold or display long Html formatted text in the JLabel, since is possible, better would be use [JEditorPanes / JTextPanes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html), these JComponets support styled and html formatted text, Icons etc ...  , examples for [JTextPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0680__JTextPane.htm) and [JEditorPane](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/0640__JEditorPane.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide us your code?  Are you setting the viewport view to the `JLabel`?  Instantiate your `JLabel` and a `JScrollPane`.  then set the `JScrollPane` viewport to the JLabel  (`setViewPortView(jlabel);`)  then add the `JScrollPane` to whatever component you want the scrolling `JLabel` to be on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @SolerMani: don't post code in a comment since as you can see, it's unreadable, but rather edit your original question and post code *with comments and text* discussing any errors and how it's not working. To Marc H, 1+ for a very good recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a `JScrollPane` to a `JLabel` , what you can do is to create a `JScrollPane` and add a `JLabel`.

See this: http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/HCI/HCI_Handout_CALLER/node63.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `JScrollPane`'s viewport view:

> scroller.setViewPortView(area);

stick that line just before you go `panel.add(scroller);`

Let us know if that helps or not.