# ScrollPane not showing on JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jlabel

When I run this program, I don't see a scrollbar on the Label. What am I missing?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Util1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Util1();
    }

    public Util1()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new ExamplePane());

                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true); 
            }
        });
    }

    protected class ExamplePane extends JPanel 
    {
        public ExamplePane() 
        {
            final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            final JLabel message = new JLabel("<html>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello</html>");

            message.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
            JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane( message, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
            scroller.setViewportView(message);

            panel.add(scroller);
            add(panel);
        }            
    }        
}
```

Comment: This `message.setPreferredSize` is a bad start

Comment: Change the layout manager.  I took out `panel` and set `ExamplePane`'s layout manager to `BorderLayout`

Comment: I suppose the html is causing it.     Maybe the first answer here helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9335138/add-a-jscrollpane-to-a-jlabel

Comment: @MadProgrammer - removing the setPreferredSize did not change anything.

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Are ScrollPanes not usable in GridbagLayout. I have narrowed down this code from a bigger code - it's not possibl eto change to BorderLayout

Comment: @ThoFin my code is doing the same thing as the first answer.

Comment: @user93353 I would say that the `FlowLayout` of `panel` is not suitabe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see a scrollbar wrap the "message" JLabel into JPanel and then add this JPanel to JScrollPane like bellow:

```
    public ExamplePane() {
        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        final JLabel message = new JLabel("<html>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello<br>Hello</html>");
        message.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));

        final JPanel messagePanel = new JPanel();
        messagePanel.add(message);

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(messagePanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

        panel.add(scroller);
        add(panel);
    }
```